# Download file for reading question using HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

If I have a URL to a download, `www.website.com/myfile.html` 
so when that link is clicked it automatically starts a download, which may be `myfile.txt` for example, how would I get that file into C# for reading..

Is that what `Net.WebRequest.Create(url)`, `Net.HttpWebRequest` does?

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this using [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx):

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    // Download and save the file locally
    client.DownloadFile("http://www.website.com/myfile.html", "myfile.html");
}
```

If you don't want to store the file locally but only read the contents you could try this:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    string result = client.DownloadString("http://www.website.com/myfile.html");
}
```

Comment: does this still work if the .html file is just a link to the download?

For my link, when I visit the url in my browser, it automatically starts a download..

Comment: It depends. If there's javascript on the page then it won't work. You will need to forge the request to the final url allowing you to download the file.

Answer (score 0):

Using C# as an example, here is how one might force the download of a file after clicking a button, link, etc...

```
public void DownloadFileLink_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Get the file data
    byte[] fileBytes = Artifacts.Provider.GetArtifact(ArtifactInfo.Id);

    //Configure the response header and submit the file data to the response stream.
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + "myDynamicFileName.txt");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
    HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(fileBytes);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
}
```

With this in mind, what you need to look for is the Header in the response, the Header will contain an item **Content-disposition** which will contain the filename of the file being streamed in the response.